# Returning share error view in ViewComponent

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

A `ViewComponent` is invoked from a `View` with a parameter passing in.

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("StudentDetails", new { id = 1 });
```

In the `StudentDetailsViewComponent` class, I have to make sure the student (id=1) is existed in the DB before returning the view. If the `id == null` or `student == null`, an error view will be returned. However, the usual `NotFound()` that we use in controller cannot be used here.

**My question is:** Is there any proper way to return an error page that can be shared among all other `ViewComponents`?

What I am doing now is to create an `Error.cshtml` under each of the `ViewComponent` folders so that it can be returned.

```
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return View("Error");
    }

    var student = await _context.Students
               .AsNoTracking()
               .SingleOrDefaultAsync(i => i.ID == id);

    if (student == null)
    {
        return View("Error");
    }

    return View(student);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use relative paths like

```
return View("../../Error");
```

or

```
return View("../../../Shared/Error");
```

Comment: could you use ~?